# Celery with Rabbit MQ Virtual Host not accepting tasks from app.tasks.py in Django

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, vhosts

Help needed!

PS: I have already created Virtual Hosts using this link

### [Celery and Vhosts](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html#setting-up-rabbitmq)

## settings.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://flash:flash_education@localhost:5672/flash'
```

---

## celery.py

import os
from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
app = Celery(
    'flash_education',
    namespace='CELERY',
)
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

---

## app1.tasks.py

```
import datetime
import json

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(name="ping")
def ping():
    print("pong")
```

---

Attaching images from my terminal, one of of the worker instance 
other is of the shell from which I am firing the tasks.
Note: I started both after settings and all but it does not seem to work

[Worker terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsff8.png)

[shell instance firing the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PCu5.png)

RabbitMQ, Celery==4.4.2 Django==3.0.4
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be late!
So the Solution to this was that I missed the settings to be added in the base **project **init**.py** pertaining to celery.
Adding the details fixed my issue!